# How to not interrupt each scrollView and NSTimer execute programmatically?

Tags: iphone, multithreading, uiscrollview, nstimer

Scrolling of Scrollview and NSTimer is affected by the main thread, so I can not handle two tasks simultaneously.

When specific time occur Scrolling, How to programmatically deal with two task(NSTimer, Scrolling)?

MyView add a Scrollview and at the same time every second animation NSTimer are executing.

However, while scrolling ,NSTimer does not works animation. the works are hold(They wait in Queue.) at the end of the Scrolling(called a scrollViewDidEndDecelerating), waiting works animation perform.

**While scrolling, I would like to work simultaneously NSTimer.**

Comment: Try putting your animation on a second thread (NSThread)

Comment: How to write a Code? as i know of that NSTimer should be execute on MainThread. How to execute BackgroundThread?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide any code so I am just going to write one way you could split your task in to two different threads.

To move an animation to be running in a background thread so it doesn't get interrupted use:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(METHOD_NAME) withObject:nil];
```

example:

```
-(void)doStuff{
    //Whatever you call here will be executed on main thread.
    NSLog(@"This is main thread");

    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(animate) withObject:nil];
}

-(void)animate{
    //Whatever you call here will be executed on a background thread.
    NSLog(@"This is background thread");
}
```

Don't overuse threads, they use a lot of resources. Use them whenever it is necessary.